# Angular ngFor rerender trackBy when changing the array position

Tags: angular, sorting, ngfor, iterable, angularjs-track-by

I want the `ngFor` not to re-render when the id change the index/position on the array.
The `trackBy` method not working as I expected in this situation.

Consider code below, In the TS File

```typescript
  users: User[];

  constructor() {
    this.change1();
  }

  change1(): void {
    this.users = [
      { id: 1, name: "one" },
      { id: 2, name: "two" },
      { id: 3, name: "three" },
      { id: 4, name: "four" },
      { id: 5, name: "five" },
    ];
  }
  change2(): void {
    this.users = [
      { id: 3, name: "three" },
      { id: 5, name: "five" },
      { id: 1, name: "one" },
      { id: 2, name: "two" },
      { id: 6, name: "six" },
    ];
  }

  identify(index: number, item: User) {
    return item.id;
  }
```

and html

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users; trackBy: identify">
    {{user.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<button (click)="change1()">change 1</button>
<button (click)="change2()">change 2</button>
```

Clicking on the buttons changes the view yet the value of each of the id is still the same
Here is an example on [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tudhdx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Awesome for the stackblitz. Wouldn't returning the `index` over `item.id` work?

Comment: Thanks :) returning the `index` not working good, it counts the length of the array. I've changed the stackblitz to show it. You can switch the comment there.

Comment: If you want the order to remain same work with the same object. Do not reassign a new object to the existing reference in the change methods.

Comment: Also, once you make this change in the identify function `identify(index: number, item: User) {     return item.id;   }` the order does change but if you open the developer tools and navigate to the **Elements** tab you will see that the object with id two never gets re-rendered implying that the *trackBy* works as expected.

Comment: @Nicholas k that is obvious, that’s not the question. trackby doesn’t rerender all the items if you added or deleted one here and there.. it does that when you change the entire order of the array. Change1() works but change2() doesn’t.